# Hidden text field value that is inside the form not appearing upon a radio button being clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have to hide or show Site div dropdown  based on radio click option and the hidden text field, appMajor value. When Radio button is "Y" and Major is "EN" Site div dropdown is visible otherwise it should be hidden.
 I have problem accessing the appMajor hidden value. This is how far I have reached.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var  selectedDecision =" ";
  $(".submitDecision ").on("click", "input:radio[name=decision]",function(){

var formId = $(this).closest("form").attr("Id"); //
var strMajor = formId.find("#appMajor").val(); //TypeError: formId.find is not a function

if ($(this).attr("value")== "Y" && strMajor =="EN"){
  selectedDecision =  "Y" ;    
  $("#selectSiteCodeDiv").show();
}
else if ($(this).attr("value")=="N" && strMajor !="EN")  {
  selectedDecision =  "N" ; 
  $("#selectSiteCodeDiv").hide();
}
else if ($(this).attr("value")=="C" && strMajor !="EN") {
  selectedDecision =  "C" ;
  $("#selectSiteCodeDiv").hide();
}
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>submit demo</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<body>

<h1> This is a Demo </h1>

<table id="exampleTable" border="1" cellpadding="10" align="center">

<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
</td>

<td>
  <input type="checkbox">
</td>

<td>
  <input type="file">
</td>

<td>
  <form class="submitDecision" id="submitDecisionform' ||sNum||'">
    <div class="decisionMessage"></div>
    <input type="radio" id="decisionAccept"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"  checked="" value="Y">Accept

    <input type="radio" id="decisionDeny"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"   value="N">Deny
    <input type="radio" id="decisionClear"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"   value="C">
    Clear Decision
    <input type="hidden" id="sNum" value="">   
    <input type="hidden" id="appNum" value="">   
    <input type="hidden" id="appMajor" value="">  
    <div style="font-weight:bold;margin :10px 0px 10px 0px;"> Deny reasons</div>
    <select id="denyReason" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
      <option value="0">*** If denied, please make a selection ****</option>
      <option value="1">Reason1</option>
      <option value="2">Reason2</option>
      <option value="3">Reason3</option>
      <option value="4">Reason4</option>
    </select> <br>
    <b>Site</b> <span id="site_span"></span><br>
    <div id="selectSiteCodeDiv" class="selectSite" style="font-weight:bold;margin :10px 0px 10px 0px;">
      <select id="selectedSiteCode">
        <option value="0">*** Please make a site selection ****</option>;

        <option value="A">SiteA</option>
        <option value="B">SiteB</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p> </p><br>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
  </form>
</td>

  <tr>
<td>
  <input type="button" value="Input Button">
</td>

<td>
  <input type="checkbox">
</td>

<td>
  <input type="file">
</td>

<td>
  <form class="submitDecision" id="submitDecisionform' ||sNum||'">
    <div class="decisionMessage"></div>
    <input type="radio" id="decisionAccept"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"  checked="" value="Y">Accept

    <input type="radio" id="decisionDeny"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"   value="N">Deny
    <input type="radio" id="decisionClear"  name="decision" class="decisionRadio"   value="C">
    Clear Decision
    <input type="hidden" id="sNum" value="">   
    <input type="hidden" id="appNum" value="">   
    <input type="hidden" id="appMajor" value="">  
    <div style="font-weight:bold;margin :10px 0px 10px 0px;"> Deny reasons</div>
    <select id="denyReason" style="margin-bottom:1em;">
      <option value="0">*** If denied, please make a selection ****</option>
      <option value="1">Reason1</option>
      <option value="2">Reason2</option>
      <option value="3">Reason3</option>
      <option value="4">Reason4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <b>Site</b> <span id="site_span"></span><br>
    <div id="selectSiteCodeDiv" class="selectSite" style="font-weight:bold;margin :10px 0px 10px 0px;">
      <select id="selectedSiteCode">
        <option value="0">*** Please make a site selection ****</option>;

        <option value="A">SiteA</option>
        <option value="B">SiteB</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <p> </p><br>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit">
  </form>
</td>
  </tr>    
</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a lot closing tags missing... Like `</input>` for example. Check your `table` and `form` structure too. You should make an effort on your HMTL code before trying to apply some jQuery on it. ;) Paste your HTML [here](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to see what is to improve. That would be my very first step. ;)

Comment: Have to say that, when I edited your post, I added `});` to close your ready function... Hoping your snippet would work. But you have additionnal error anyway. Paste in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) to look for error.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette, Think you for your advice. I will try to check my error and get back.

Answer (score 0):

```
formId.find("#appMajor").val()
```

isn't working. Try

```
$("#appMajor").val();
```

instead. (You shouldn't have to use "find" since it would be very bad practice to use the identical ID more than once on the same page...)

Then that input field, #appMajor, is never going to have any value, since

```
<input type="hidden" id="appMajor" value="">
```

How is a hidden input field ever going to get the value "EN"? Or does that value automatically get added (or not) via PHP? If it does, then the changes above should do the trick. Also, maybe remove the

```
checked=""
```

from your radio buttons so the user needs to actually pick an option.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/674kcnrc/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  appMajor is not populated with correct value. to have value during the execution. It is a outline of code.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  appMajor will have a value during execution that piece coming from database. appMajor has different values like EN,AG,ON etc for different rows. However if EN is in First row and second has AG. $("#appMajor").val(); will give me always EN not AG .

Comment: So... The problem is that the database is giving you the wrong value, not the jQuery code? Because if I manually add "EN" to the hidden input field, it works as it's supposed to: https://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/674kcnrc/2/

Comment: Or are there multiple input fields with the ID appMajor? That would be very bad practice... An ID should only appear once on a page. If that's the issue, you could change it to `<input type="hidden" class="appMajor" value="" />` and change the code to  `var strMajor = $(this).next('.appMajor').val();` or something similar. https://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/674kcnrc/3/

Comment: There is only one appMajor hidden field. $this.('#appMajor') is not providing correct value. If I have two rows I get strMajor value from first tow even though I clicked the second row.